# How do you debug production issues in a Vue app

Tags: vue.js, vite

I am fairly new to Vue 3. While I have used Vue 2, it has been mostly in the context of a `<script>` tag embedded in an `html` or `jsp` page.

I recently found myself in a situation where a Vue application worked as expected in development mode (through `nodejs / vite` but the application would behave unexpectedly when built and copied into a python flask server.

To my horror, I found that VueJS will not produce any output to the console in production.

So, what happens if a network resource suddenly becomes unavailable or a databse was modified unexpectedly and this only affected the production environment? This seems like a huge oversight! Obviously, I am missing something! Are there any best practices or recommended ways to handle errors in a production application built with VueJS

Comment: Maybe use a hidden `<div>` to write debug information?

Comment: it's not best practice to spew debug information to end users in production so of course it will be hard to debug in such an environment where debug info and tools are turned off, but any issues from changes to network resources or databases should be evident in similar dev environment.  It's not an issue with the framework.  Don't make untested changes to production resources without testing in dev first.  This is software engineering best practice, not just Vue.

Comment: Obviously errors will be found in production code. It is impossible to make 100% bug-proof code.  A properly maintained dev environment however should be able to reproduce any bug discovered in production where you can properly debug and fix.

Comment: You can use [Sentry.](https://sentry.io) to catch runtime exceptions and perhaps some Promise rejections. But my recommendation is to switch to SFC (single-file components) in Vue and a proper bundler (Vite or Webpack) and fully decouple from the Python code through a proper REST API.

Comment: You need to be able to reproduce the problem in local environment this includes switching a backend in case it's different in dev, devserver proxy allows to prevent cors problems.. Debugging in prod is the last resort and also a useful skill. There's "vue force dev" extension for vue devtools for this. If an app has some flag to enable user's dev mode from console, this may help. Make sure sourcemaps are working ok, otherwise you may end up in a very uncomfortable situation debugging minified code (which is also a useful skill).

Answer (score 0):

To debug a production build you could turn off minification:

```
npx vite build --minify=false
```

Then use the devtools to step/breakpoint debug and find your problem.

> So, what happens if a network resource suddenly becomes unavailable or a databse was modified unexpectedly and this only affected the production environment? This seems like a huge oversight! Obviously, I am missing something!

That's not a problem of Vue, Vue is a framework not a CMS.
Make your own API error handling, display appropriate toasts, log errors into something.